# Unity reference "current" game object confusion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm having issues trying to reference/loop through game objects.

I have 2 arrays of game objects, each object has a rigidbody component (same prefab).

Lets say I want to have two players take turns shooting one of the objects.

I was thinking something like this

```
GameObject currentObject;
        void Game()
        {
        if(player1turn)
        currentObject = player1Object[shotsTaken/2];
        else if(player2turn)
        currentObject = player2Object[shotsTaken/2+1];


        shoot(currentObject);
        shotsTaken++;
        if(player1turn){player2turn=true;}
        else
        {
        plyer1turn = true;
        }
        }

    void shoot(GameObject obj)
    {
    obj.GetComponent<RigidBody>().velocity = new Vector3(0.0f,10.0f,0.0f);

    return;
    }
```

It seems like I can't reference the "currentObject", says no rigidbody when I try to set its velocity.  Thanks for any suggestions.  I'm sure there is a nice clean way to do this.

Comment: This isn't a coding question, but one of how you setup your prefab (and instantiate it). Otherwise the script looks ok.

Comment: Script looks OK. Check there are RigidBodies on the GameObjects, also check the RigidBody isnt on a parent or child, if so use the appropriate GetComponent variant. Also,it would be much more efficient if you store all those RigidBodies in an array at runtime rather than using GetComponent during play.